# how to use a value from one component to another component

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have 2 component.

First: component.ts 
ts.

```
@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    myid: any;
    myappurl: any;
    constructor(private router: Router, private auth: LoginService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        }
        handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
            console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);
            this.myappurl = appURL
            console.log(this.myappurl)
            let url_1 = this.myappurl.toString();
            let url_id = url_1.split("/").reverse()[0];
            this.myid = url_id
            let LS = require("nativescript-localstorage");
            LS.setItem(this.myid)
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/test/resetPasswordRequest', this.myid); //show correct this.myid
        }); 
    console.log('this.myid', this.myid)  // show null

     }
}
```

.html

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

Second: another component. I want to get `this.myid` and use in another component.

```
    export class ResetPassIdComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor() {}
      ngOnInit(){
      this.resetPasswordForm = this.fb.group({
      'password': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'myid': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
       });
      }
onReset() {
console.log(this.resetPasswordForm.value)
  }
    }
```

routing.ts

```
{ path: 'resetPasswordRequest', component: ResetPassIdComponent }
```

Any idea pelase,how to get this.myid in ResetPassIdComponent  ?

Thanks

Comment: store it in a service or pass it via route resolvers. Both solutions are described in the docs of angular

Comment: A basic example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: Many of the people commenting here are not taking into account that the code above is NativeScript and not Angular for WEB. Here is the master-details template for NativeScript-Angular which is showing how to use the NativeScript's `router extensions`https://github.com/NativeScript/template-master-detail-ng

Comment: Another NativeScript demonstration here https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/c147d0bee1c6ddd7150bd74b9d6cf99fdd319250/app/pages/rovers/photo-detail.component.ts#L32-L33

Comment: You could also use the Angular ActivatedRoute as shown here https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation#passing-parameter

Answer (score 3):

You can either use A service or pass it through route

```
 this.router.navigate(['/test/resetPasswordRequest', this.myid]);
```

And resolve it from another component

```
export class ResetPassIdComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router:Router) {}
  ngOnInit(){
    let param = this.router.routerState.root.queryParams 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes,How to get it from the first components and use it in the second component `myid` ?

Comment: `this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")`

Comment: console.log( this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get("id"))
show null

Comment: Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Router'.ts(2339)

Comment: use `routerState` for angular 6 >

Comment: `JS: param {
JS:   "_isScalar": false,
JS:   "observers": [],
JS:   "closed": false,
JS:   "isStopped": false,
JS:   "hasError": false,
JS:   "thrownError": null,
JS:   "_value": {}
JS: }`

Comment: Maybe the problem is in my routing.ts ? I have this `{ path: resetPasswordRequest', component: ResetPassIdComponent }`

Comment: then change like this `this.router.navigate(['resetPasswordRequest', this.myid]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use route navigation to pass an ID. However make sure you get proper value of myId before routing to another page.

```
this.router.navigate(['/test/resetPasswordRequest', this.myid]);
```

To receive it in another component you can use following:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

export class ResetPassIdComponent implements OnInit {

  id: any

  constructor(
     private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
     this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => { this.id = params['myid']; });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please check that "this.myId" has proper value assgined in AppComponent? Also before doing this.router.navigate('PATH') you must get "this.myid = url_id" in AppComponent.